# Double mapped relation in symfony? It is possible?

Tags: symfony, double, mapping, entity

I have no ideal how to double map entity in symfony.

I have table

```
Matches
________
id    

u_id1 : reference to user

u_id2 : reference to user

status: enum
```

Now i don't want to create double records per one match.

I want to load user matches where `u_id1 = user_id or u_id2 = user_id`.
So.. i want make my method in user object inteligent usefully . eg $user->getMatches(); what returns matches where first or second u_id have current user id.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this.
Define two relations in User entity

```
class Matches {

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userOneMatches")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="u_id1", referencedColumnName="id")
         * **/
        protected $u_id1;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userTwoMatches")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="u_id2", referencedColumnName="id")
         * **/
        protected $u_id2;
}
```

and in User entity method `getAllMatches();` to combine all matches.

```
class User {
    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Matches", mappedBy="u_id1" **/
    protected $userOneMatches;

    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Matches", mappedBy="u_id2" **/
    protected $userTwoMatches;


   public function getAllMatches()
   {
    // return $userOneMatches + $userTwoMatches
   }

}
```